# Update google sheet based on ID column on my website backend is active?

Tags: google-sheets

I am using google sheets to maintain a google product feed.

Often times we will have to de-activate a product on our website e-com back end and then go into the google sheet and change the status column from in stock to out of stock manually.

I was wondering if it is possible fully within google sheets to check on our website back end if the product is marked inactive (based on the product ID column) to change the status column.

I know there are ways to import html in sheets but I have not seen anything that can check if html is changed especially on a password protected admin page.

Answer (score 0):

formulas from import family cluster (`IMPORTHTML`, `IMPORTXML`, `IMPORTRANGE`, `IMPORTFEED`, `IMPORTDATA`) are not able to bypass any kind of password protection (eg. they can't look/import data behind login access)

Comment: Hmm ok, I might be able to make something either export to a public location. Or I can just check if the URL says product not active  then mark the product as out of stock.

Comment: if you do so (export to a public location) then you can scrape it with IMPORTHTML/IMPORTXML and then use VLOOKUP with combo of ARRAYFORMULA

Comment: I was actually able to do it using IMPORTHTML and RegExMatch but it looks like I quickly hit the google sheets limitation of (I think ) 50 queries? The sheet is about 1000 rows long so I don't think this will really work

Comment: yes for 50 queries. better would be to import it all (with 1 formula) in new sheet and then trim it to your needs